# How to keep all related projects together when GOPATH forces you to put code in /go folder

Tags: git, go

I want to start developing a go web service at the following path:

```
/dev/git/proj1/mygoservice/
/dev/git/proj1/railsapp/
```

If my go path is at:

```
~/go
```

How will this work?  Should I create a symbolic link to my git repo?

I want to keep all my sub-projects grouped together under teh /dev/git/proj1 path.

Comment: You need to put your code in GOPATH. That's just a fundamental requirement for using the `go` tool.

Comment: @JimB so a symbolic link won't work?

Comment: The go tool purposely excludes symlinks to prevent linking the same packages multiple times. If you must access it through multiple paths, link _to_ the source which is in GOPATH.

Comment: One thing is your GOROOT and another is your GOPATH. GOPATH Should be used for your projects,, I suggest also follow this structure in your GOPATH (https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces).
symbolic links would work, but a.- is not the recommended way and b.- (by my own experience) you will be fighting against the language.

Comment: Is this a public project (with github repo) or just a private one?

Comment: I think the simplest way is to define GOPATH according to your current project. You can have multiple values in GOPATH by separating them with colon (":").

Answer (score 2):

If you *have* to keep your sources in `/dev/git/proj1`, then you would need indeed a symlink from your sources to the official GOPATH `~/go/src` (respecting a [workspace structure](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces)).
And not the other way around, from `~/go/src` to your sources.

That is because go tools don't follow symlink, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066068/how-to-keep-all-related-projects-together-when-gopath-forces-you-to-put-code-in/47068255?noredirect=1#comment81098972_47068255) by [JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb)
([issue 15507](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15507), [issue 17451](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17451))

So:

```
cd /dev/git/proj1
mv mygoservice ~/go/mygoservice
ln -s ~/go/mygoservice
```

But if you need to push your git repo to a GitHub project, then it would be best to use the right folder structure in order for your Go project to be go gettable, as seen in "[Import paths](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportPaths)":

```
mkdir -p ~/go/src/github.com/<auser>
cd /dev/git/proj1
mv mygoservice~/goo/src/github.com/<auser>
ln -s ~/go/src/github.com/<auser>/proj1/mygoservice /dev/git/proj1/mygoservice
```

That way, you will use within your go sources the right import path based on "`github.com/<auser>/mygoservice`"

Comment: The go tool elides symlinks to prevent the same code from importing from multiple paths. This is going to lead to difficult to track down build failures.

Comment: @JimB Strange, I have been using symlink for years without issue (while editing the code within GOPATH)... although... I see what you are saying: https://github.com/tools/godep/issues/71

Comment: Yup. It’s been rejected multiple times, for example https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15507 and https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17451

Comment: @JimB https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17451#issuecomment-255180808: You could instead symlink ~/myproject -> your GOPATH. OK. It works in that direction.

Comment: yes, That's what I always have done in these cases, which is what I mentioned in the comments above. Regardless, you still need to setup your GOPATH in line with the official documentation, so there's not much to add here.

Comment: @JimB OK, I have rewritten the answer accordingly.